# Importing a file using Workbench returns 0 files when using column matching

Tags: mysql, import

I am completely new to SQL. I asked that question 2 weeks ago but got no reply, so I am afraid I have to ask again.
I am trying to import a file into mySQl using Workbench. When I import the full file into a new table, this works perfectly. But what I am trying to do is to import the file into an existing table, specifying column matching. I use Table Import Wizard and get the message that the file was imported in 0.25s but that 0 rows were imported. I thought it my be because of different data type between the file and the existing table, so I tried to simplify my import to just one column, even so, it doesn't work. No error, but nothing imported. However, when configurating the import settings, I see the data in the file perfectly.
What can it be ?

I have added some screen shots:
Situation 1, screenshot 1-2-3: i import the file as it is, without touching the field names, imports all data perfectly
Situation 2, screenshot 4-5: i try to import some fields only, and force them into an existing table, therefore I have to indicate to the wizard where it fields has to go. 0 rows imported

I tried removing the header line, doesn't make any difference, still 0 imported

(if you do not see the links, I have pasted them again in comment below)

Comment: are you removing the header to the file when you import?

Comment: This is a whole lot of words and not much in the way of a concrete example of what you're trying to do. Sample code or queries help considerably.

Comment: I am not using any code. What I do is the following: right clicking on table name, select table import wizard. Situation 1: I import my table with all the fields are they are described in the first line of the csv file, no problem, everything gets imported. Situation 2: the problem is I am trying to force the imported data into an existing table which has different column name, so when importing I have to tell the wizard that I want to import column XX into field YY. When I do that, nothing is imported. I did try removing the header, makes no difference.

Comment: Not sure if you see my screenshots, the links I embedded do not seem to show:   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMyeo.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfCW4.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlKz7.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvZbN.png
  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVkkB.png

Comment: anyone can help ?

Comment: still not solved. any help?